# Redux Saga no se detiene y hace succesivas peticiones, como puedo hacer que se detenga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

estoy migrando mis servicios a `Redux-saga` la cual si ha funcionado, hace la peticion `HTTP` y puedo verlo normal con `console.log()` pero las peticiones nunca terminan, leí que `takeEvery` es la que hace continuamente, pero yo uso `takeLatest` la cual en teoria solo deberia hacer una peticion, pero este no termina nunca

**home.js**

```
function Home() {
  const { Banners} = useSelector((state) => state.HomeData);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  const initdata = async () => {
    if (Banners?.length == 0) {
      dispatch(A_HOME_DATA());
    }
  };

  console.log(Banners);//logged:  []

  useEffect(() => {
    CVGoUp();
    initdata();
  }, []);
```

**Action**

```
export const A_HOME_DATA = (data) => ({
  data: data,
  type: 'HOME_DATA'
});
```

**Reducer**

```
const tstate = {
  Banners: [],
  loading: true
};

const HomeData = (state = tstate, { type, data }) => {
  if (type == 'HOME_DATA') {
    return { ...state, ...data };
  }
  return state;
};

export default HomeData;
```

**Service**

```
const homeservice = async () => {
  const result = await AxiosGQL(HOME_SERVICE);
  return {
    response: {
      data: result,
      code: result != null ? 200 : 500
    },
    error: result == null
  };
};

export default homeservice;
```

**Saga**

```
function* fetch() {
  const { response, error } = yield safe(call(homeservice));

  if (response) {
    if (response.code >= 200 && response.code < 300) {
      yield put(
        A_HOME_DATA({
          Banners: response?.data?.Banners,
          loading: false
        })
      );
    }
  } else yield put(A_HOME_DATA({ error }));
}

export function* watchFetch() {
  yield takeLatest('HOME_DATA', fetch);
}

function* WPSagas() {
  yield all([fork(watchFetch)]);
}

export default WPSagas;
```